# Spring JDBC Template java.lang.ClassCastException in spring 4.0.0

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I am new to Springs. I am trying to run JDBCTempalte example. I got ClassCastException. It doesn't make sense to me.

My Context file

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<!-- I have removed my config, I have tried JDBC code it is working with this datasource-->
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcDAO" class="com.sarma.spring.jdbcEx.JDBCDAOImpl">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/><!-- This is my jdbc example it is working-->
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

my main class

```
try{
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate jdbc = (org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate)context.getBean("jdbcTemplate");
String query = "SELECT ACNT_NBR FROM eit.ACNT WHERE ACNT_ID=13057";
int o= jdbc.queryForInt(query);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output

```
2013-10-08 16:43:34 INFO  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:513 - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1c672d0: startup date [Tue Oct 08 16:43:34 EDT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
2013-10-08 16:43:34 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:316 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
2013-10-08 16:43:34 INFO  DriverManagerDataSource:133 - Loaded JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy12 cannot be cast to org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
    at com.sarma.spring.jdbcEx.main.JdbcExMain.main(JdbcExMain.java:45)
```

My 45 line is

```
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate jdbc = (org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate)context.getBean("jdbcTemplate");
```

Did I make any mistake?? Thanks for your help

Thanks,

CVSR Sarma

Comment: Is that all that's in your context? I see no reason why Spring would be proxying your `JdbcTemplate` (unless it's a 4.0 feature).

Comment: Its not full context I have deleted some context. 
I was running AOP but not in this main class, I am not using for this example

I have common context file doing all examples using one context file

Comment: If you get rid of the AOP stuff, does the error remain?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I commented my AOP it worked. Do you know why didnt work before?

Comment: It's possible some AOP advice had to be applied to a `JdbcTemplate` method and therefore the bean had to be proxied.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, It make sense to me. Thanks for quick response. much appropriated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Spring bean is not usually proxied unless some special external behavior needs to be applied. For example, [AOP advice](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-schema), [transaction management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html), [bean scope](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes), etc.

Your context seems to be incomplete. If you've declared some AOP joinpoint that matches a `JdbcTemplate` method, then that bean will be proxied. You can specify proxy settings, [for example if Spring should `proxy-target-class` instead of the interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying). If you have the CGLIB library on your classpath, you shouldn't have any problem by setting

```
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true"> ...
```

A small example of JDK proxies

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate();
    Object proxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(template.getClass().getClassLoader(), template.getClass().getInterfaces(), new ProxyJdbcTemplateHandler(template));
    System.out.println(proxy.getClass());
    System.out.println(proxy.getClass().getSuperclass());
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(proxy.getClass().getInterfaces()));
}

public static class ProxyJdbcTemplateHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private JdbcTemplate target;

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
            throws Throwable {
        // do something with target
        return null;
    }

    public ProxyJdbcTemplateHandler(JdbcTemplate target) {
        this.target = target;
    }
}
```

prints

```
class $Proxy0
class java.lang.reflect.Proxy
[interface org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations]
```

The proxy has the type of the superinterface of `JdbcTemplate`, but not the type itself. Its parent class is actually `Proxy`. For that you will need to use CGLIB proxies, by providing CGLIB jars on your classpath and specifying `proxy-target-class="true"` in your configuration.

Comment: I still don't understand how the proxy would be a problem. A proxy is useless if it doesn't have the same type as the proxied object. So, the proxy should be an instance of JdbcTemplate.

Comment: Got it. The OP uses the default JDK interface-based proxies, and the proxy thus has the type of the interface implemented by JdbcTemplate: JdbcOperations. If he used CGLIB-based proxies, the proxy would be an instance of JdbcTemplate. +1.

Comment: @JBNizet I was in the process of writing a small example, you're too quick.